# Magento version 1.9.2 404 on add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ce-1.9.2.0, 404

Ok let me start from the beginning;
The site I am currently working on is Magento powered E-commmerce website. I was given the site after 3 developers took the owners money and ran once they got confused. The website was version 1.9.1 and I updated the website to 1.9.2 The owner of the website contracted ecorepay to handle the credit card purchases from the site. Ecorepay sent me a module extension which I uploaded per ecorepays instructions. Ecorepay was installed before update was made to the website. After the update is when the problem started. Once store item is selected to add to cart it goes to a 404 page not found and doesn't add to cart.

and this is the url that got me here
www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/myadd/?product=4&qty1

When a product link is clicked for selection it doesn't add the item to the cart. Before update of the website it would add to cart then take you cart page and checkout pages where you put all your billing and shipping information.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any custom extension installed? If you view source on the product detail page, what is the form action url?

Comment: Please add more informations: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

The default magento link to add a product to the cart ist

```
www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/add/?product=4&qty=1
```

So you have some extension installed, which changes add to myadd. Obviously this action isn't implemented or wrongly configured.